# Check for hierarchical index in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3), index=[[(2015, 8, 16), (2015, 8, 17), (2015, 8, 17)]])
print(data)
print((99,99,99) in data.index)
```

produces unexpected behavior:

```
                  0
2015 8 16  1.496188
       17  1.766312
       17  1.487920
True
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I properly check for a hierarchical index?**

As an aside, strangely this code:

```
for x in data.index:
    print(x == (99,99,99))
    print(x == (2015,8,16))
```

does the right thing:

```
False
True
False
False
False
False
```

Though clearly not desirable.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in master, nor 16.2. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.14.1 ... but I would assume this functionality would be rock solid since the very first code for hierarchical indexing...

Comment: i updated pandas (via Anaconda) and can confirm it works in the new version ... must have been a bug